# SQL SERVER: WHERE clause in subquery to get attribute from outer query

Tags: sql-server, subquery, where-clause

So here is the query

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
(SELECT
    Country_Region AS CR,
    WeekOfYear,

    (SELECT SumConfWeekly FROM
    (
        SELECT Country_Region, SUM(ConfirmedWeekly) AS SumConfWeekly
        FROM covid_19_aggr
        GROUP BY CUBE (Country_Region)
    ) AS C
    WHERE C.Country_Region=T1.CR) AS SC2,
    ConfirmedWeekly
FROM 
    covid_19_aggr
)
AS T1
PIVOT(
    SUM(ConfirmedWeekly)
    FOR WeekOfYear IN ([4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14])
) AS PT1
ORDER BY SC2 DESC;
```

The problem is in the where clause, where I want to match Country_Region from the subquery to the outside query. How to go about this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
(
    SELECT
        Country_Region AS CR,
        WeekOfYear,
        (
            SELECT SumConfWeekly FROM
                (
                    SELECT Country_Region, SUM(ConfirmedWeekly) AS SumConfWeekly
                    FROM @covid_19_aggr
                    GROUP BY CUBE (Country_Region)
                ) AS C
            WHERE C.Country_Region=T2.Country_Region
        ) AS SC2,
        ConfirmedWeekly
    FROM 
        @covid_19_aggr T2
)
AS T1
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ConfirmedWeekly)
    FOR WeekOfYear IN ([4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14])
) AS PT1
ORDER BY SC2 DESC;
```

Comment: @Tathagata sometimes formatting the code in a slightly better way helps. AHTH!

Comment: this is my first time taking a database course, I'm noob ;-;

Comment: @Tathagata you are doing gr8, you can use [this](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-refactor.aspx) to format the code always.